# App starts to crash after upgrade to SDK 31 Android

Tags: android, google-signin, android-pendingintent, appodeal

**Edit**
I removed `Appodeal`, `explorestack:consent` and `jcenter` and now it works. `Appodeal` did not build without `jcenter` which is deprecated. I am not really sure where the problem lies, but one of the above should be the problem.

I recently updated the libraries in my `build.gradle` and the targetSdkVersion. After testing it and uploading to Google Play I suddenly started to get crashes:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.name.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
       at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
       at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
       at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:86)
       at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:75)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

and

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.name.app/com.name.app.Activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:374)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am not using `PendingIntent` maybe some of the libraries does? The google button has never been any problems before.

Here are the `build.gradles`:

App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Apply the Google Services plugin (if it's not there already).
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31

        versionCode 91
        versionName "91"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal" }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'

    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0'

    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation 'com.explorestack:consent:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation('com.appodeal.ads:sdk:2.10.2.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks', module: 'amazon_ads'
        exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks', module: 'appodeal'
        exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks', module: 'nast'
    }
}
```

Project:

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? I have not been able to reproduce it.

It crashes in `LoginActivity`, which is the start activity. Here is the `AndroidManifest` for that part:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="Name"
    android:exported="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

       <data
           android:scheme="http"
           android:host="name.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: have you upgraded android studio to Artic Fox?

Answer (score 6):

In your first stack trace it is indicating that the work manager is crashing while trying to create a `PendingIntent`:

```
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
```

Since it is running on a different thread, one cannot see the origin. I had the same issue in my project and it turns out it was a library dependenig on a work manager library version < `2.7.0`. `2.7.0` is the [first version of the work manager library which is ready for Android 12](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#version_27_2).

The troubling dependency in my case was `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'` which was depending on `androidx.work:work-runtime:2.1.0`. I solved it by pining a fixed version of `androidx.work:work-runtime` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
constraints {
    implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0') {
        because 'play-services-ads depends on work-runtime:2.1.0 which is not compatible with targetSdk 31, but work-runtime:2.7.0 is'
    }
}
```

This will force `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` to use `work-runtime:2.7.0` instead.

My hunch is that in your case this is the problematic dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0'
```

If not, you can use the following gradle command to find all libraries which are depending on `work-runtime`:

```
./gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --dependency work-runtime --configuration debugCompileClasspath
```

Look for the ones that are depending on `work-runtime` version smaller than `2.7.0` and pin `2.7.0` to them as I described above.

Hope that helps .

Answer (score 2):

I meet the similar problem with you.
Try to add: implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0' in your gradle file to be able to create your project.(even though you are NOT using anything in that library)

refer to： https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/Yu5cemkP7fY

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error I found in my app this dependency to be the problem: `com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.0.0`

Removing it stopped my app from crashing. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way yet to use it without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

For apps with 31 target sdk you must set exported flags to your android components with intent-filters.
You can read more in official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

your component in manifest file must be like below

```
<activity android:name="LoginActivity" android:exported="true">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I have already added `android:exported="true"`, the question is updated.

Comment: have you another android components with intent filters in manifest file?

Comment: No, I do not have that.

Comment: are you create any PendingIntents in your app? if yes then check your ```getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, @Flags int flags)``` method. Maybe last parameter necessarily to be set

Comment: No, I am not creating any PendingIntents. I do not know if any of the libraries do that.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try updating your dependencies

2.And Rebuild your project

Comment: I have been able to reproduce it on a simulator now. I still don't understand where this intent comes from.